# QNetworkAccessManager not releasing memory

Tags: c++, qt, memory, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm using Qt 4.7. My my sync process is using a different thread. We use the QNetworkAccessManager in order to apply to the server to perform the sync. I noticed that all the memory used by the QNetworkReply its never release.

After reading several pages and had different test, I understand that its not a memory leak as some people stand, but its a problem of releasing the memory. Actually its even acceptable to have this memory used, but obviously, since im working in embbeded, as more memory as better (not only for embbeded).

The thing is that every time we sync (60 sec) the memory does not increase, but after the delete later, it also does not free it.

Although its not very orthodox, im using Top to check the memory usage.

My code:

```
Sync::Sync(const Settings &settings)
{

net_manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
reply_ = 0;
}
```

Get the status from url:

```
 void Sync::get_status()
{
QUrl url(status_url);

connect( net_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(reply_status(QNetworkReply*)) );

reply_ = net_manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));

connect(reply_, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
        this, SLOT(slDownloadFilesError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));

}
```

And the reply fucntion:

```
void Sync::reply_status(QNetworkReply* reply)
{

   if ( reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError ) {
       qDebug()<<"[Sync]" << "..........NETWORK ERROR: " << reply->error() << "\nERROR STRING: " <<reply->errorString();

       sl_freeMemory();
       return;
   }

sl_freeMemory();

//Do whatever...

}
```

Last part:

```
void Sync::sl_freeMemory()
{
if(reply_ == 0)
    return;

disconnect( net_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(reply_status(QNetworkReply*)) );

disconnect(reply_, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
        this, SLOT(slDownloadFilesError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));

reply_->abort();
reply_->deleteLater();
reply_ = 0;


}
```

I really appreciate any kind of hint you can give me. I checked several sites and the logic its the same as the one im using.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Following the advice of @vahancho i did the following modifications. 
Every time i want to sync i create the networkmanager with

```
net_manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this); (Inside get_status()).
```

In the sl_freeMemory() i added

```
net_manager->disconnect();
net_manager->deleteLater();
```

Nothing change, does not increase / decrease or release the memory.

Comment: Why didn't you call `net_manager->deleteLater()` too?

Comment: " I noticed that all the memory used by the QNetworkReply its never release" - how do you measure memory consumption?

Comment: @vahancho net_manager->deleteLater() doesnt make any difference, i just retry it and nothing. I measure if I comment the     reply_ = net_manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url)); and the connects my app is 97M. If I uncomment, raises up to 122M. I'm thinking now that maybe the QNetworkReply doesnt consume so much memory and is  QNetworkAccessManager how is eating it. Thanks guys for the heads up

Comment: Just pass `reply` as an argument of `sl_freeMemory()`. You are doing potential memory leaks here.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I've done it and still, memory its never release.

Comment: You didn't. Check your code.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Privet! I didnt added to the question here, but I tested in my code without any result.

Comment: Try to create an http://www.sscce.org/ . Your code looks OK